# syntax error, unexpected ')' in laravel 8. \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider.php:51

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

**I'm trying to send a notification from a laravel 8 app."**
When I hit the URL I get the error. syntax error, unexpected ')'
In the route file :

```
Route::get('/twitter', function (){
    Notification::route(TwitterChannel::class,'')->notify(new TestNotification());
});
```

In notification file

```
public function via($notifiable)  {
    return [TwitterChannel::class];
}
public function toTwitter($notifiable)
{
    return new TwitterStatusUpdate('Laravel notifications are awesome!');
}
```

In composer.json file

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "laravel-notification-channels/twitter": "^5.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
},
```

The error page screenshot is :
[The error page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sIIt.png)

Comment: you are using the wrong version of PHP

Comment: check your php version first using php -v. 
this will not print exact php version all time time. that's why you should use <?php phpinfo(); ?> in code

Answer (score 12):

Laravel 8 requires PHP >= 7.3. You are using a lower version than that which is why it does not support the trailing comma in function calls.

The error is the proof that you are using the wrong version.

[PHP.net Manual - 7.3 Features - Trailing Commas are allowed in Calls](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration73.new-features.php#migration73.new-features.core.trailing-commas)

Comment: My PHP version is 
PHP 7.4.10 (cli) (built: Sep  1 2020 16:52:21) ( NTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

Comment: you are using the wrong version ... there are multiple versions on your system (7.4 is just what the CLI is using) ... again the error is the proof

Answer (score -1):

It's seem like a comma issue on line 50 end.

Thanks

Comment: this is supported in PHP >= 7.3

Comment: Please provide more information - an answer should not only inspect the error, but also provide a way to resolve it